# Environment Variables macOS & WIndows

Tags: macos, terminal, windows-10, environment-variables, macos-catalina

In Windows' Environment Variable Tab, the User Variable and System Variables are separated. I have a MacBook Pro and would like to add new 'user' variables like Windows. Is this possible? I mean I found there are temporary variables that can be created in the Terminal, but if that Terminal is closed, the variables are gone. I found a way to do a permanent variable, but do not want to mess things up in the core of the macOS. Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

If you set variables in the ~/.bash_profile file, they will always exist since this file is automatically run every time you open Terminal.

To edit it:

`vim .bash_profile`
(i to insert text, esc to exit insert mode, :q! to discard and quit, :x to save and quit)

Then add:

```
export VARIABLE_NAME=value
```

Save and quit the editor (:x). Then to check if it worked:

```
echo $VARIABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

When the terminal is bash, editing the .bash_profile works.
If you're using zsh, then edit
 ~/.zsh and add the command as
""export variableName = value"" in to the file
Now,  run
""source ~/.zsh""